# VBA Excel Workbooks.Open works only if I have opened it manually first

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small VBA script in an Excel file to open another xlsx file (in the same folder) in a Windows network (2012 R2).

I get the error 1004 (file not found) if I try to run the script (from a button) after I open  but if I open the targeted file manually first and than I close it, the script run correctly when I call it...

I tried it **locally** on Mac OSX with Excel 2016 and Windows 7 with Excel 2013, with 2 different files (name) and I get the same problem even if I'm not in the network. I also tried with different users to test the privileges.

I also tried to remove space and other special chars and I get the same result.

I know it could be related to the security as the file contain macros and an ODBC call but I don't find what could fix that.

Here's the script:

```
Sub Ouvrir_donnees_commandeventes_actual_ibm()

StopCalc
Workbooks.Open "Compilation vente en ligne (VTE_LIGNE).xlsx"
StartCalc

End Sub
```

Anyone can help me to find what cause the error please?
Thank you

Comment: To actually open it you will need to use the full path like: `"C:\Compilation vente en ligne (VTE_LIGNE).xlsx"` otherwise it only looks at the open workbooks.

Comment: Try this `Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path &  "\Compilation vente en ligne (VTE_LIGNE).xlsx"` if they are in the same path.

Comment: Thank you @Peh, this works on Windows, as answered by user3005775 the PathSeparator method will help in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the full path you can do this

```
Workbooks.Open(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "/Compilation vente en ligne (VTE_LIGNE).xlsx")
```

also remember the forward slash is required on a mac, if you are running it on windows you need to change to a `\` backslash, or use the `Application.PathSeparator` instead of hard-coding the back/forward slash.

```
Workbooks.Open(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Compilation vente en ligne (VTE_LIGNE).xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you @user3005775, can I ask why you call the method from "Application"? Because it also works without.